# Ошибка при импорте "from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection"

Tags: python

Мой код:

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os

execution_path = os.getcwd()

detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "resnet50_coco_best_v2.1.0.h5"))
detector.loadModel()
detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(execution_path , "input.jpg"), output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path , "output.jpg"))
```

Ошибка:

```
 from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
2021-12-01 22:55:53.147595: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-12-01 22:55:53.153409: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from imageai.Detection.YOLOv3.models import yolo_main, tiny_yolo_main
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection\YOLOv3\models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
ImportError: cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'keras.layers.normalization' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\normalization\__init__.py)
```

У меня версия python 3.9.0, я пытался обновить библеотеку imageai, не помогло, прошерстил все сайты, на сайте с документацией нашел код, вставил его но все равно не работает, подскажите что делать??

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте импорт `BatchNormalization` по другому:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
```

Comment: Если я поменяю импорт то выходит ошибка Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\User\imageai\import math.py", line 7 in <module> detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet() AttributeError: 'BathNormalization' object has no attribute 'setModelTypeAsRetinaNet'